# What is the probability that a man arrives at work later than on the previous day but not more than 5 minutes later.?

Tags: probability, self-study

A man leaves his house at the same time every morning and the time taken for journey to work has the following probability density function:

$f(t) = \  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 &; t<30  \\
      k &;30<t<60 \\
      2k &;60<t<70 \\
      0 &;70<t  \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

What is the probability that on one particular day, he arrives at work later than on the previous day but not more than 5 minutes later.?

**Attempt:**

Let the man reach office on day $1$ at the $x^{th}$ minute and on day $2$ at the $y^{th}$ minute.

Then, the required condition is as follows:

$y-x \le 5\\y>x\\30<x,y<70$

Our area of interest is the area bounded between the above curves.

Lets find out the value of $k:  ~k(60-30)+2k(70-60)=1\implies k=\frac{1}{50}$.

With reference to the diagram attached, The required answer is $\sum A_k . P(A_k)$ Where $A_k$ belongs to the bounded region defined above and $P(A_k)$ is the associated probability density with that area.

Is my method correct? Because when I calculate based on the above, I get a final answer $>1$ which is absurd. ( Please see the diagram )

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank You![image]

Comment: (1) Draw a picture of the region. (2) *Integrate* the density.

Comment: @whuber I did. I got an answer > 1

Comment: @DilipSarwate sir I drew it. Getting an answer > 1. That's where I am encountering a problem here

Comment: Your probabilities are not correct. You have _two  independent_ random variables $ X$, the time of yesterday's arrival, and $Y$ the time of today's arrival. The probability that $Y -X \leq 5$ must be computed as a _double integral_ of the _joint_ pdf over the region that you have shown, and not the single integrals you write. So, what is the joint pdf? (Hint: it does not have value $k$ or $2k$ anywhere).

Comment: @DilipSarwate The joint pdf should be $X(t_1)~ Y(t_2)$ (i.e the product of independent variables $X$ and $Y$). Am I correct?

Comment: No, what you say is incorrect. You need to learn about joint pdfs before proceeding.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This is not my homework. I do not attend college currently. I am self -studying a book called mathematical statistics to prepare myself for graduate studies.

Comment: OK. Since you are self-studying, read the relevant materials on joint pdfs and how to calculate probabilities from them.